# Tabs and tab stops in flutter text

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter application that displays text send by a server that contains tabs (`\t`).

The goal now is to have the text aligned at tab stops using the text, as it is done by text editors.

Unfortunately `Text` and `RichtText` seem to ignore the `\t` symbol or handles it as a normal space.

In addition, I want the text to be selectable. So rendering every tab stop in its own text widget is not really an option, because then the text is not selectable across multiple tab stops.

Comment: you can use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html

Comment: That plugin does not allow the text to be selectable